# Nuclear-Fusion related Question on Spin

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

I was studying Nuclear Fusion and came across this nuclear reaction.
I've read that the spin of all particles is conserved in any nuclear reaction.

[image]

I was really intrigued because that meant that Protium should have a spin of its own too.
I know that the spin of a Positron is equal to (-0.5) and a Neutrino has one of (+0.5).

If Protium is given a spin *a* and Deuterium is given a spin *b*, then by the conservation of spin:

(*a* + *a*) = (*b* - 0.5 + 0.5)

Therefore, (2*a* = *b*); that means that Protium has half the spin of Deuterium.
It also has half the number of nucleons. I started to think that spin might depend on nucleons.

So I had a few questions on this; do atoms have spin and also, is their spin equal to their nucleon count?
Like Protium might have a spin of 1, Deuterium might have a spin of 2 and so on.

I also felt it might not be equal to nucleon counts, but just depend on if its even or odd.
Like Protium has 1 nucleon, hence it might have a spin of 1/2; and because Deuterium has 2 nucleons, it has a spin of 1.
And maybe Tritium has a spin of 1/2 again because it has an odd number of nucleons, i.e., 3.

I just started with the law of spin conservation, and I don't know if my assumptions here are right. Could someone help give some clarity on this stuff and tell me if there are any conceptual mistakes I've made?

Comment: Yes, protons are spin 1/2 particles.